# Recyclerview and RestApi

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I get Data of MS Sql Server by RestApi but i can't Set on `Recyclerview`. I read two String objects of DataBase name and url of image.

I can't just set data on `Recyclerviewadapter`

Please Help me or show me correct example

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<SingleItemModel> feedsList;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    new AsyncLoadDeptDetails().execute();
}


protected class AsyncLoadDeptDetails extends
        AsyncTask<Void, JSONObject, ArrayList<SingleItemModel>> {
    ArrayList<SingleItemModel> recModel = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("WrongThread")
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<SingleItemModel> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = api.SingleItemModel();

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            recModel = parser.parseDepartment(jsonObj);
            adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, feedsList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = jsonObj.optJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
                SingleItemModel item = new SingleItemModel(i);
                item.setName(post.optString("title"));
                item.setUrl(post.optString("thumbnail"));
                feedsList.add(item);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("AsyncLoadDeptDetails", e.getMessage());

        }
        return recModel;
    }
  }
}
```

**SingleItemModel**

```
public class SingleItemModel {


private String name;
private String url;


public SingleItemModel(String name, String url) {
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
}



public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

**MyRecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private List<SingleItemModel> singleItemList;
private Context mContext;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<SingleItemModel> singleItemList) {
    this.singleItemList = singleItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
    final SingleItemModel feedItem = singleItemList.get(i);

    //Download image using picasso library
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(feedItem.getUrl())) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getUrl())
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(customViewHolder.imageView);
    }

    //Setting text view title
    customViewHolder.textView.setText(feedItem.getName());


    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(feedItem);
        }
    };
    customViewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(listener);
    customViewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != singleItemList ? singleItemList.size() : 0);
}


class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView imageView;
    protected TextView textView;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}


public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
    return onItemClickListener;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<SingleItemModel> feedsList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    feedList = new ArrayList<SingleItemModle>();
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, feedsList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Override `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask` call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` since you add items to `feedList` in `doInBackground`.

Edit :

Change this

```
   SingleItemModel item = new SingleItemModel(i);
```

to

```
   SingleItemModel item = new SingleItemModel();
```

There is no constructor that takes i as a param in  model class.

Comment: I have Error with by i object in  SingleItemModel item = new SingleItemModel(i);

Comment: Remove i from that. You need ro check your model class constructor

Comment: Please check my question again

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but you have initialised the adapter when your feedsList was empty, so it will not display anything. what you need to do is overide the onPostExecute() method and move

```
adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, feedsList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

these two lines to the onPostExecute method (executed after the doInBackground implicitly). By doing so you would have added items to the feedsList before passing it to the adapter or another way around

Hope this helps.

Comment: logcat error is RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: is it showing the item in recyclerView or just giving the error.

Comment: Do not display anything , but i get data of sql server by restApi